# Draw rectangles next to each other in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, draw

I'm learning to code in Java. I have this assessment that I need to do: I have to create a java app that will do the following:

- Allow the user to specify the number of input rectangles (between 3 and 30).
- Generate the requested number of input rectangles (with random widths and heights) and write them to a file (human readable).
- Read the randomly generated input rectangles from the file generated in the step above.
- Display the input rectangles graphically, correctly laid out NEXT to each other
- Calculate the output rectangles.
- Display the output rectangles graphically, correctly laid out aside each other. Note: Both the input and output rectangles must be displayed at the same time.
- Write the output rectangle coordinates into an output file (human readable)."

There rectangles are simple boxes (not fancy coloured etc). I have been struggling with this code, managed to get the Input + error handling done and it displays the rectangles but not as the desired.

Bugs: I need it to accept the amount of rectangles from the user and display them NEXT to each other.

Please find my code below... Thanks in advance.
LB

---

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class final_rect extends JFrame
{

    public final_rect()
    {
        setTitle("tutorial");
        setSize(700,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
              int x = 50;
              int y = 50;
              Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i=1; i <=5; i++)
        {
            int width = rnd.nextInt(200);
            int height = rnd.nextInt(200);
        System.out.println("Rectangle["+ i +"]" + ":(W="+width+ ";H=" +height +")");

        g.drawRect( x , y , width, height);

// Update the coordinates for the next rectangle.
                  x =  x + width;
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 3 and 30!");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a number! Please enter a number between 3 and 30!!!");
        sc.next();
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
} 
while (number <3 || number > 30);

System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + number);

test1 t = new test1();
        t.paint(null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way:

you could make a start position x and y (like 0,0), and keep adding the width to x and/or height to y, and use them on the next retangle to be drawn, instead of fixing the start position (that will make them inside each other).

Oh, just to make sure you know: `drawRect(int startX, int startY, int width, int height)`

Comment: Thank u Montolide, i have tried it, g.drawRect(205 + width ,300 ,height,width); Certain rect. stil over lapping.Its cos i used random W/H. Playing around with the code now.. The rectangles are also being drawn pointing down, like its attached to the ceiling and coming down. I need it to be on the ground and growing up. I tried using a 0 axis but still having the prob. Any suggestions? The other thing is that i need the program to accept an input from the user to draw the amount of rectangles.. for now in my code i used 'i<5' just to test the drawing. Please assist :-) LB

Comment: The `(0,0)`position is the top-left point of the JFrame, so you need to draw your retangle from the height of the jframe minus your rect height to the height of the JFrame (bottom of the JFrame). `getHeight()` will help you. About the (205+width), you're losing the last position for every retangle drawn, try using a variable to keep this value. Same goes to your variable `number`, try making it acessible to the `paint` method :)

Comment: Thanks 4the reply, I solved the overlapping problem, I did as u said using a variable `x =  x + width;` The rectangles now display NEXT to each other :-). Its still displays from ceil but its not a big prob, the main thing i need to do is get the code to accept user input and output that amt of drawn rectangles. I tried returning the value & making it accessible to the 'paint method', but no luck :-( Can you kindly assist me maybe step-by-step on this one or with a working example. I really appreciate you taking the time in helping me :-)

Comment: You can use a field of the final_rect class, like `private int numberOfRects`, and assign it in the main method `numberOfRects = number`, after this you can use it on the main method. As a side note, use the class name like this: `FinalRect`, you're working with Java ;)

Comment: Maybe I'm saying too much 8| you should try doing it alone, lol. About the ceil, reemember that the (0,0) point is the top-left, and the (JFrame.getWidth(), JFrame.getHeight()) is the right-bottom, maybe you can work some logic to make the rects be in the place you want :)

Answer (score 2):

You are drawing them on top of each other. This line:

```
g.drawRect(205,300,height,width);
```

draws the rectangles all starting at the point (205,300).

You have to change the values of the first two arguments (possibly only one of them). I'm not going to give you the exact code because this is homework but:

you have a starting location, call it (205,300) like in your code, you have the width of each rectangle as you draw them, with this information you should be able to figure out what the next location is.

Another thing is you are creating a new `Random` object everything through the loop you should only create one at the top of the method (or for the entire class at constructor time).

Comment: Thanks Guys, @Montolide, i have tried it, 

    g.drawRect(205 + width ,300 ,height,width);

Certain rect. stil over lapping.Its cos i used random W/H.
Playing around with the code now..

The rectangles are also being drawn pointing down, like its attached to the ceiling and coming down. I need it to be on the ground and growing up. I tried using a 0 axis but still having the prob. Any suggestions?

The other thing is that i need the program to accept an input from the user to draw the amount of rectangles.. for now in my code i used 'i<5' just to test the drawing.
Please assist :-)
LB